# C# do-while increases process memory in every loop. How to fix?

Tags: c#, loops, memory, while-loop

I'm working in a C# program for automatically reboot my DSL router if it's down. I wrote this so far:

```cs
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net;

namespace RebootRouter
{

    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]

        static void Main()
        {
            bool ProgramLoop = true;
            do
            {
                CheckAndRun();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(180000);
            }
            while (ProgramLoop == true);
        }

        public static void CheckAndRun()
        {
            if (ScreenSaverCheck.IsScreenSaverRunning() == true)
            {
                if (InternetCheck.IsConnected() == false)
                {
                    string FirefoxBinary = (string)Registry
                                   .GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\    
                                   Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\
                                   App Paths\firefox.exe", null, false);
                    Process LaunchMacro = new Process();
                    LaunchMacro.StartInfo.FileName = FirefoxBinary;
                    LaunchMacro.StartInfo.Arguments = "imacros://run/?
                                                   m=RebootRouter.iim";
                    LaunchMacro.Start();
                }
            }
        }

        public class ScreenSaverCheck
        {
            public static bool IsScreenSaverRunning()
            {
                Process[] FullProcessList = Process.GetProcesses();
                foreach (Process ProcessFromList in FullProcessList)
                {
                    if (ProcessFromList.ProcessName.EndsWith(".scr"))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
        public class InternetCheck
        {
            public static bool IsConnected()
            {
                try
                {
                    IPAddress[] GoogleIPAddressList = Dns.
                                          GetHostAddresses("google.com");
                    if (GoogleIPAddressList[0].ToString().Length > 6)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works as intended, but the problem is the process increases its memory usage in like 15 KB each time it loops. It's normal or there's a way to optimize? Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Does the launched process end before the next time interval? If yes, CLR will reclaim this memory eventually. But since `Process` implements `IDisposable`, you might want to  keep the previous instance in a field and dispose it manually before creating a new instance.

Comment: You should definitely dispose the process ... but how many times did the loop run?  Spotting a memory leak based on a small number of iterations is tricky -- you may just be seeing an artifact of how heap memory is managed.  I'd try running it for 100,000 iterations and seeing if it is stable.

Comment: And btw, if you wrote a macro for FF yourself, you might as well write the appropriate C# code to do the same thing to avoid opening FF completely.

Answer (score 1):

I added:

```
public static void CheckAndRun()
{
    if (ScreenSaverCheck.IsScreenSaverRunning() == true)
    {
        if (InternetCheck.IsConnected() == false)
        {
            string FirefoxBinary = (string)Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\firefox.exe", null, false);
            using (Process LaunchMacro = new Process())
            {
                LaunchMacro.StartInfo.FileName = FirefoxBinary;
                LaunchMacro.StartInfo.Arguments = "imacros://run/?m=RebootRouter.iim";
                LaunchMacro.Start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class ScreenSaverCheck
{
    public static bool IsScreenSaverRunning()
    {
        Process[] FullProcessList = Process.GetProcesses();
        try
        {
            foreach (Process ProcessFromList in FullProcessList)
            {
                if (ProcessFromList.ProcessName.EndsWith(".scr"))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            foreach (Process ProcessFromList in FullProcessList)
            {
                ProcessFromList.Dispose();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and then I tested with:

```
static void Main()
{
    int MyInteger = 0;
    do
    {
        CheckAndRun();
        MyInteger = MyInteger + 1;
    }
    while (MyInteger < 100000);
}
```

It's stable now. Memory doesn't go more than 5 MB. Thank you very much Douglas and Rob Walker.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, you should take care to dispose all objects whose class implements the `IDisposable` interface – in your case, `Process`.

For example:

```
using (Process LaunchMacro = new Process())
{
    LaunchMacro.StartInfo.FileName = FirefoxBinary;
    LaunchMacro.StartInfo.Arguments = "imacros://run/?m=RebootRouter.iim";
    LaunchMacro.Start();
}
```

When dealing with an array:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
try
{
    foreach (Process p in processes)
        if (p.ProcessName.EndsWith(".scr"))
            return true;
}
finally
{
    foreach (Process p in processes)
        p.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll add that to my code, however the memory increases even when Firefox is not launched. Any ideas?

Comment: It might be due to the other `Process` instances not being disposed.

Answer (score 0):

You should kill existing firefox processes before launching new ones. Not being connected does not automatically mean that the process is not running anymore.